# In Django ORM filter objects by annotation on the group by

Tags: django, django-models, group-by, django-orm

I have this model and I need to filter all the objects A where the daily duration, for the same user, is greater than a value X.

```
class A(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    day = models.CharField(choices=["monday", "tuesday" ... "sunday"])
    duration = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: Do you mean "the sum of all daily durations for a user is greater than x"?

Comment: I think this is more  a modeling problem: you should make a model `A` that has a `user`/`date` couple, and then a model (`B`) that has an FK on `A` and has a duration, then this is quite easy.

Comment: @IainShelvington no. 
I mean "I want all the objects where their daily_duration is greater than x"

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree it would have been much easier in that way.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment my solution is the following, but it seems pretty ugly to me:

- first I group by user and day annotating the daily duration and filtering on it
- then I filter again by couples (user, day) coming from the first query

```
group_by_user_day = A.objects
    .values("user", "day")
    .order_by("user", "day")
    .distinct()
    .annotate(daily_duration=Sum("duration"))
    .filter(daily_duration__gt=X)

q_objects = Q()
for item in group_by_user_day:
    q_objects |= Q(user=item["user"], day=item["day"])
results = A.objects.filter(q_objects)
```